# MySQL in termux giving no output

Tags: mysql, mariadb, termux

Mysql in termux is giving no output whenever I try to display database or table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do these commands work? This is what I use in mysql2, and based on the mariadb shell documentation, these appear to be right. Also to select data from a table, you use SELECT * FROM [tablename] when you are using a database (meaning after you type "USE [dbname]).

So try this

`SELECT * FROM soft_drinks;`

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-data-from-mariadb/

sources:
[https://rtfm.co.ua/en/mysql-mariadb-most-used-commands-with-examples/)](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/mysql-mariadb-most-used-commands-with-examples/)
https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/cs10.6/sql-statements/

## Working with databases

To create a database:

`mysql> CREATE DATABASE [databasename];`

List all databases on the current MySQL server:

`mysql> SHOW DATABASES;`

Connect to a database to start working with it:

`mysql> USE [db name];`

### Description

SHOW DATABASES lists the databases on the MariaDB server host. SHOW SCHEMAS is a synonym for SHOW DATABASES.

The list of results returned by SHOW DATABASES is based on directories in the data directory, which is how MariaDB implements databases. It's possible that output includes directories that do not correspond to actual databases.

Examples

```
SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```